# Black and white image conversion to array and back?

Tags: c++, image

I am looking to take a black and white image and convert it into a bit string representing each pixel with a 1 or 0. A list or array would work as well.

I am then looking to convert in the opposite direction, from a string or array to an image.

This is in C++.

Comment: What's the purpose of this please? Is it academic - i.e. for learning or do you just want to get the job done?

Comment: academic, I want to be able to play around with the image as bits and then output a new image

Comment: Look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format at `P1` format images. ImageMagick can turn any image into one with `magick image.jpg -threshold 50% -colorspace gray -compress none result.pbm` and the other way too.